# Setting precise voltage offsets with over_voltage

Tags: config.txt, overclocking

On the BCM2711, the base VCore was greatly lowered from previous processors, though the `over_voltage` setting still uses 0.025V increments. On my Pi 4, `vcgencmd measure_volts` returns 0.8563V when not overvolted and 1.0063V at `over_voltage=6`, the highest allowed without tripping the warranty bit.

However, it seems the Raspberry Pi 400, which uses a [newer stepping of the BCM2711](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/119356/differences-between-b0-and-c0-steppings-of-the-bcm2711), ships with `over_voltage=0x11170` by default. I have not seen hexadecimal values for this setting documented anywhere, but as far as I can tell, this corresponds to an offset of 70,000 microvolts (0.07V), just shy of `over_voltage=3` (0.075V).

Given that `over_voltage=6` corresponds to a 0.15V offset, can I safely use an arbitrary value between `0x0` and `0x249F0` for precise voltage offsets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I just tried `over_voltage=0xEA60` (+0.060V offset) with a 1.7 GHz overclock and it works as expected:

```
pi@azazel:~ $ vcgencmd measure_volts
volt=0.9163V
pi@azazel:~ $ vcgencmd measure_clock arm
frequency(48)=1700419968
```

So the answer is yes, you can enter the voltage offset in microvolts by specifying a hexadecimal value. The warranty bit was not tripped (the revision number is still `c03112`).

I have not found how to enter a negative offset this way and I'm not willing to experiment any further at this point. Any comments adding more information would be appreciated.